# Gears, distance, cadence = Speed

Tags: chainring, speed

My bike is a Giant "Revolt" and I have a speed/Cadence sensor (from Giant). It doesn't always record accurately. But my question: **I'm looking for a Chart** that gives me the distance traveled & speed when I'm in a specific combination of gears with a constant cadence. So I'd like to know from this chart if I have gears(front & back of course) with 'x' number of teeth and my cadence is ie 65rpm's what speed am I going and what distance have I traveled.

Comment: You realize a $10 bik computer will how you speed and distance? And your cadence is probably too low. It should be 70 -90

Comment: Part of the question is that the speed/cadence function isn't too accurate in this case (maybe he measured things against a smart phone, which also isn't great with accuracy?). It may be that he hasn't setup the sensor and computer right (calibrating it and what not for wheel size and stuff), but question still stands.

Comment: The distance you travel also depends on the wheel size, which varies according to which tires you are using.

Comment: Since this question has pretty quickly, received two answers that are [equally valid](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), I'm going to close it as a service recommendation. However, it's possible that it could be reworded to ask how to calculate what you're looking for and be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

[Sheldon Brown's gear calculator](http://sheldonbrown.com/gears/) shows you speed at certain cadences (in multiples of 20 rpm) as a function of chainring size, cassette size, crank length and wheel size.

For what its worth, most people should be using a cadence in the 70-90 rpm, so you're on the lower end.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one as it supports multiple parameters
It is a calculator and a chart

[BikeCalc](http://www.bikecalc.com/speed_at_cadence)

Multiply speed by time to get distance

12 mph X 1.5 hours = 18 miles

Comment: I like this site.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you like that particular tool? Also, what does the video you've linked to have to do with answering the question?

Comment: Batman [provides context](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for his link. I.e., he says what it does. Your post is basically a link-only answer (with two links). I don't see how that video does a good job of explaining anything. As I see it, it's just a guy mocking the woman he supposedly loves for not understanding something that he sees as self-explanatory. His "explanation" of mph is just rephrasing.

Comment: @jimirings What do you want me to do?  If you want me to delete the video then just say that.

Comment: I didn't have a strong feeling about it, I just didn't think it was a helpful video. I see you deleted it though. And I closed the question as a service recommendation, so the point is moot.